# When are "cron.monthly" cron jobs run?

Tags: linux, cron

I want to run `yum` updates on a monthly basis which is actually running daily now.

Can I move `0yum-cron` from `cron.daily` to `cron.monthly`? If yes, then how can we know which time and day of the month its going to run?

Comment: What Linux are you using? (I don't know if this matters, but it may well help to know)

Answer (score 5):

Within reason you can move anything you like between the `cron.hourly`, `cron.daily`, `cron.weekly`, `cron.monthly`.

But be careful because if you remove/move a config file installed by a package-manager such as yum then a future system upgrade might try to add the config file back.  So when you move it, you might want to leave a blank file in it's place...  I can't guarantee this will prevent yum from overwriting it in future.

Typically timings are configured from an entry in `/etc/crontab`.  If you can't find anything there then check the files in `/etc/cron.d`

For example, on ubuntu server there is a default crontab configured specifying:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

According to this, my server will run it's /etc/cron.monthly scripts as `root` at `6:52` on the 1st of every month.

Comment: Also note that the timings of these various entries has had to be varied according to what they do.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/505637/5132

Comment: I think this will depend on the anacron configuration (when it is installed). When you look at this crontab, you see that it does not run anything in the last 3 lines, when ``/usr/sbin/anacron`` is present. So you need to check an additional config.